# How to call a function on multiselect change

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 dropdown and 2 multiselect. here I am getting the bus leaving and coming date for a specific bus.

[screen-shot-issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAqoc.png)

Date difference function is not calling when I select or deselect the dates after page load. It works properly when I change this date from Bus leaving dropdown.

Comment: Please provide your script or code that you have tried.

Comment: $(document).on('change', '#leaving_dates, #coming_dates', function() {/*here is my logical with ajax request*/})

Comment: place the code to execute first time or on load inside `$(document).ready()` or `$(window).onload()` methods

Comment: I have tried ready as well as onload but non of them is working.

Comment: @Developer107 : I have tried with $("body").on('change', but its is not working.

Comment: @Rajiv then please provide your entire code as we can't assume without knowing what the problem is

Comment: @Developer107: ok please wait